# How do I monitor a "stuck" Python script?

Tags: python, sockets, scripting, urllib2, freebase

I have a data-intensive **Python** script that uses HTTP connections to download data. I usually run it overnight. Sometimes the connection will fail, or a website will be unavailable momentarily. I have basic error-handling that catches these exceptions and tries again periodically, exiting gracefully (and logging errors) after 5 minutes of retrying.

However, I've noticed that sometimes the job just freezes. No error is thrown, and the job is still running, sometimes hours after the last print message.

What is the best way to:

- **monitor** a Python script,
- **detect** if it is unresponsive after a given interval,
- **exit** it if it is unresponsive,
- and **start** another one?

---

**UPDATE**

Thank you all for your help. As a few of you have pointed out, the **urllib** and **socket** modules don't have timeouts set properly. I am using **Python 2.5** with the **Freebase** and **urllib2** modules, and catching and handling **MetawebErrors** and **urllib2.URLErrors**. Here is a sample of err output after the last script hung for 12 hours:

```
  File "/home/matthew/dev/projects/myapp_module/project/app/myapp/contrib/freebase/api/session.py", line 369, in _httpreq_json
    resp, body = self._httpreq(*args, **kws)
  File "/home/matthew/dev/projects/myapp_module/project/app/myapp/contrib/freebase/api/session.py", line 355, in _httpreq
    return self._http_request(url, method, body, headers)
  File "/home/matthew/dev/projects/myapp_module/project/app/myapp/contrib/freebase/api/httpclients.py", line 33, in __call__
    resp = self.opener.open(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 381, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 399, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 360, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 1107, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 1080, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/httplib.py", line 928, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/httplib.py", line 385, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/httplib.py", line 343, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/socket.py", line 372, in readline
    data = recv(1)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

You'll notice the socket error at the bottom. Since I'm using **Python 2.5** and don't have access to the third **urllib2.urlopen** option, is there another way to watch for and catch this error? For example, I'm catching **URLErrrors** - is there another type of error in **urllib2** or **socket** that I can catch which will help me?

Comment: Do your http requests have timeouts? Basic functions from a module like urllib doesn't have them ..

Comment: See my update below on how to set the default timeout in the socket module. Note that the default lack of timeout isn't a flaw in the socket module, as imposing an arbitrary timeout would interrupt valid socket operations that take a long time, like huge file transfers.

Comment: I have added the logic you suggested and will try another run tonight. If that does not work, I will try to modify the script to work with Python2.6 to gain the default timeouts.

Comment: The bad news is I'm still timing out. The good news is now the socket follows the same "sleep and try again" logic as other errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the program is doing web communication, I'd fire up a debugging proxy like Charles http://www.charlesproxy.com/ and see if there's anything kooky happening in the back-and-forth between your script and the server.

Also consider that the socket module has no timeout set by default and therefore can hang. As of python 2.6, however, you can pass a third argument to urllib2.urlopen (if you are using urllib2, that is), specifying a request timeout period in seconds. That way the script will error out rather than go catatonic waiting from a response from a perhaps uncooperative server. If you haven't already, I'd check these things out before trying anything more elaborate.

**Update for python 2.5:**
To do this in python < 2.6, you would have to set the timeout value directly in the socket module, which urllib2 uses. I haven't tried this, but it presumably works. Found this info at http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml:

```
import socket
import urllib2

# timeout in seconds
timeout = 10
socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)

# this call to urllib2.urlopen now uses the default timeout
# we have set in the socket module
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.voidspace.org.uk')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Comment: I am using Python 2.5, unfortunately (I've copied my results in the updated question). Is there another way to achieve this in 2.5?

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like there is a bug in your script. The answer is not to monitor the bug, but to hunt down the bug and fix it.

We can't help you find the bug without seeing some code. But as a general idea, you might want to use logging to pinpoint where the problem is occurring, and write [unit tests](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#module-unittest) to help you build confidence about which parts of your code do not have the bug.

Another idea is to break your "stuck" program with Ctrl-C and to study the traceback message. It will show you what line your program was last executing. 
That may give you a clue where the script is going wrong.

Comment: I interrupted the latest run and updated my question with the results.

Comment: @Wraith: I think twneale's suggestions are good ones to try. Also, if you are making many requests to the same server, you may want to try putting a `time.sleep(...)` command in between requests so you don't hit the server too hard. Some servers block requests from overly demanding clients.

Answer (score 1):

a simple way to do what you ask is to make use of UDP packets sent by your current program to another harvesting program that monitors the output. If it doesn't receive a packet in a certain amount of time, it kills the other python process then restarts another one

Comment: Why would the program send UDP packets?

Comment: It would also be possible to simply update a pid-like file with a timestamp, and have a caretaker check that the time is being updated reasonably.  If the program is truly locking-up, you could do the timestamp updating in another thread, without requiring any real modification to your current code.  If you find that the timestamps are still being updated after the program locks-up, then only the thread is locking up, and the answer is to use that other thread to do the monitoring.

Comment: as a method of keeping track if its running or not. Your current process will stop sending UDP packets if it locks and will make it easy to track.   @Zack, you won't want to do it in threads but in separate processes. Just using threads really isn't going to work w/ python as the threads are both locked by pythons interpretor if they're run from one process

Answer (score 1):

You could run your script in `pdb` and break in when you suspect it's frozen. It won't work on its own, but might help you figure out why it's freezing.

Comment: Can you explain further? Like my script stops working after a certain amount of URLs are scraped. How do I use `pdb` here?